# Memory efficiency of String and BigInteger

Tags: java

I have a hashtable that maps a tuple to a String initialized like this:

```
HashMap<Tuple,String> marks = new HashMap<Tuple,String>();
```

My problem is that if i have to map many and large strings(up to 30 characters) this eats up a lot of memory since i saw that a string needs `36+4*characters` bytes of memory.These strings though can contain only 2 characters:h and t.So i thought that i could instead of `h` and `t` use `0` and `1` and not store a string but some type of Integer.I found that for 19+ digits i can't work with primitive types and my only solution is BigInteger Object type.
What i would like to ask is this:will BigInteger be more memory efficient than String?
If not could i represent a String in a different way in order to use less memory?

P.S. The Strings contain only `h` and `t` so a string may be `hhhttttthhhh`.I could represent this as `h3t5h4` with 3,5,4 being the consecutive times i see a certain character but many strings may be `hthththt..` which is not optimal to be  represented this way.

Comment: Most people wouldn't consider 30 characters to be very large.  How many is "many"?

Comment: If you really want to pack your data as efficiently as possible, then instead of *decimal* digits `'0'` and `'1'`, the natural way to go would be *binary* digits `0` and `1`.  You have 32 of these available in each `int` or `Integer`, and 64 in each `long` or `Long`.

Comment: It would be much more memory-efficient to represent `'h'` with `true` and `'t'` with `false` and use a `boolean[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory usage is the only one concern you have then java.util.BitSet can be a very efficient way to store your 0 and 1 sequence. Just be aware that this comes with a CPU consumption overhead.

Comment: Is it better though?Because i read that an empty Bitset requires 48 bytes.

Comment: This is arguable. `new BitSet().size()` returns 64 but they are bits not bytes. If u inspect the new BitSet() instance you will see an one element long array which is where 64 bits size come from. However apart from very small arrays it is proved that a BitSet is more memory efficient than an array of Boolean values. In your problem you mentioned you need to map many and **large** Strings so this is why I recommended a BitSet.